# How to scale a div height during scroll AND keep it fixed to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm sure that I've seen this technique used before, but I can't seem to figure out what it's called, or find a decent example to learn from online. Seems like a basic question:

I want to make a one-page website where the site's logo is shown large when the page loads, and then gets smaller as the user scrolls down UNTIL the image reaches a certain size, then it is fixed to the top of the page, with the site's menu right underneath it, fixed to the top of the page as well.

I've tried a handful of ways to make this work. The way I've currently got it set, the content beneath it scrolls underneath the header too "quickly" and hides underneath.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsUDn/)

Markup

```
</div>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#section_1">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section_2">section_2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section_3">section_3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section_3">section_3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<div id="main">
    <div class="content_section" id="section_1">Section 1!</div>
    <div class="content_section" id="section_2">Section 2</div>
    <div class="content_section" id="section_3">Section 2</div>
    <div class="content_section" id="section_3">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;
}
#header img {
    height:100%;
}
#logo_container {
    height:200px;
    /*temporary -- this is usally supplied by height of the image inside it */
}
nav {
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul, nav li {
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    list-style-image: none;
}
#main {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:800px;

}
.content_section {
    display:block;
    border-top:5px black solid;
    height:200px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

and Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    function resizeTopLogo() {
        var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + 0,
            zeroSizeHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
            newSize = Baseheight * (1 - (winScrollTop / zeroSizeHeight) * (2 / 3));
        Node.css({
            height: newSize
        });
        $("#main").css({
            paddingTop: $("#header").height()
        })
    }

    var
    Node = $('#logo_container'),
        Baseheight = Node.height();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        resizeTopLogo();
    });
});
```

So, my question is how to make the bottom content scroll WITH the reducing-size header, UNTIL the header reaches the height at which it's supposed to remain, and then scroll independently from the header. (Then of course, it has to return to its original state when the user scrolls back up to the top of the page, but that may be another story altogether).

To be clear, I'm just just asking about fixing a div to the top of the page. I can do that. I want to reduce the size of the image WHILE fixing to the top of the page WHILE having content scroll nicely beneath it.

I've also tried putting the content underneath the header, in the same fixed div, but then the content wouldn't scroll. I tried using a dummy container to make it scroll, but then the bottom of the content wouldn't show up consistently, and it seemed unnecessarily hacky.